# Google Analytics Not Working Desipite No Errors

Tags: google-analytics

I've spent a lot of time attempting to add google analytics to my site.

The site in question is http://gentlefox.net

Using the Tag Assistant chrome extension, it shows no errors and shows that pageviews are recorded.

However in the analytics dashboard it doesn't show any activity at all. What's going on here?

Comment: How long ago did you create the Google analytics account it can take up to 72 hours for it to begin recording data.   Make sure you are checking the real time reports not the standard reports they can also take up to 48 hours to record data.

Comment: Ok that probably explains it then.

Answer (score 0):

How long ago did you create the Google analytics account it can take up to 72 hours for it to begin recording data. Also make sure you are checking the real time reports not the standard reports they can also take up to 48 hours for data to be stable in the standard reports as it must complete processing.